# Java: Detect too much injected dependencies in services

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

is there any possibility to detect automatically, if a service is injecting too much services?

toolchain: java + spring boot + sonarqube + gitlabci

```
public class TooMuchService {
  // injection
  private AService aService;
  private BService bService;
  private CService cService;
  private DService dService;
  private EService eService;
  private FService fService;
  private GService gService;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BeanPostProcessor`, like in this [article](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-post-processors/):

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor 
{
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException 
    {
        System.out.println("Called postProcessBeforeInitialization() for :" + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException 
    {
        System.out.println("Called postProcessAfterInitialization() for :" + beanName);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This way, from the `Object bean` you can get the class name for each instantiated bean. You can use reflection afterwards in order to search for annotations, add them up and check if the number is acceptable to you.

But I wouldn't worry about this number, it does not affect performance.

Comment: Hey, thx for ypur answer. I was asking, because it could be a bed smell in the architecture if a class injecting too much denepndencies #god-class.